# Programatically switching Action Bar tabs - how to attach an argument?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm switching my Android (Sherlock) Action Bar tabs like described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609745/programmatically-switch-tabs-in-android-using-actionbarsherlock): [Programmatically switch tabs in Android using ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609745/programmatically-switch-tabs-in-android-using-actionbarsherlock).
Is there any way to **pass an argument** to the called tab?

Thanks in anticipation!

---

Further information as requested by @semperfly:

My MainActivity has a ActionBar and implements ActionBar.TabListener

```
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    tabCalculate = actionBar.newTab();
    tabCalculate.setText("Calculate");
    tabCalculate.setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tabCalculate);

    tabArchive = actionBar.newTab();
    tabArchive.setText("Archive");
    tabArchive.setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tabArchive);
```

This is the implementation of the ActionBar.TabListener:

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    SherlockFragment fragment = null;
    if( tabCalculate.equals(tab) ) {
        if( fragmentInput == null ) {
            fragmentInput = new FragmentInput();                
        }            
        fragment = fragmentInput;
    } else if ( tabArchive.equals(tab)) {
        if( fragmentArchive == null ) {
            fragmentArchive = new FragmentArchive();
        }
        fragment = new FragmentArchive();
    }
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentsContainer, fragment);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}    

public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

}
```

My first approach was to load the InputFragment from the ArchiveFragment this way:

```
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            SherlockFragment fragment = new FragmentInput();
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putSerializable(FragmentInput.ARG_INPUTDATA_TO_LOAD, inputData);
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentsContainer, fragment);

            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This worked perfectly fine, but didn't switch the active tab indicator in the ActionBar accordingly, the blue line below the archive tab was active albeit the input fragment was active.

Then I tried this method to switch tabs/fragments:

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
```

This works but now I can't pass arguments to the tab to be activated.

Comment: Why do you want to pass an argument to a selected tab?
and you can call .select() on a tab if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: @user1597833 because this other tab re-uses information from the source tab. Imagine the source tab as an archive and when clicking on such an archived item it is loaded into the "input and edit"-tab to be re-edited. Thus I have to pass the old item or it's id to the "input and edit"-tab.

Comment: you can assign each tab a different view, and each view can contain an 'imageview' or some other view and you can always change the views attributes pragmatically.

Comment: My tabs are already Fragments. But I don't have a reference to the "input and edit"-fragment in the archive-fragment... (BTW: Sorry for being stupid - I'm new to android...)

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code for your onTabSelected() method?

Comment: The normal way to do this would be to handle it in onTabSelected() which should be called when you call setSelectedNavigationItem().  Or create an interface in the fragment that is implemented in the activity so the fragment can request the parameter when attached.

Answer (score 13):

Late, but you can use:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1); //where 1 equals the 2nd tab
```

Comment: I am using this approach to switch to another tab but  I think this recreates the view on the selectedtab and for me the view is null. So I am getting a nullpointer exception. Is there a place where I can see what exactly this is doing? I am using fragmenttransaction.replace.

Comment: Can you please provide the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this could be the answer to my question
[Fragments - Creating event callbacks to the activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)

Comment: you can pass a parameter to a fragment, but remember to create a public empty constructor to the fragment as well.

Comment: As I'm switchin my tabs by this code: "getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(0);" I fear this won't help me.