# Action Bar switching tabs automatically:

Tags: android-actionbar

I am implementing an app where user can search some songs in a separate tab.The search results for a song are info like lyrics, meaning etc. From the results, user can mark certain songs as favorite which are in another tab. When I click on the favorite songs tab, it should switch to the first tab with fragment for the search results. Here are more specific details:

- Main Activity spawns action bar which creates 2 tabs.
- Search Tab - Separate Fragment, Results-  separate fragment
- Favorites Tab - Separate Fragment

  ```
  public class TabsListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
      private Fragment mFragment;
      private final Activity mActivity;
      private final String mTag;
      private final Class<T> mClass;

  /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
    * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
    * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
    * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
    */
  public TabsListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
      mActivity = activity;
      mTag = tag;
      mClass = clz;
  }

  /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
      // Check if the fragment is already initialized
      if (mFragment == null) {
          // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
          mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
          ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
      } else {
          // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
          ft.attach(mFragment);
      }
  }

  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
      if (mFragment != null) {
          // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
          ft.detach(mFragment);
          //ft.remove(mFragment);
      }
  }

  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
          ft.attach(mFragment);
      // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
  }
  ```

  }

How can I implement this switching from one tab to another programatically for Action Bar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609745/programmatically-switch-tabs-in-android-using-actionbarsherlock it should be similar without using Sherlock.

Comment: Ok, that worked, now how do I load the song in the first tab with all the details? Is there a way the first tab can know that it got invoked from another tab? The first tab can have three possible fragments. The search fragment, song list fragment and the details fragment. So the fragment could be any of these three. I am guessing it should be in the tablistener class I mentioned above but is that right ?